# PHP Ajax file upload without redirect at the end

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

i have seen a lot of ajax file upload examples, all with jquery and also the dirty use of iframes. Can anyone suggest an example without jquery and also progress bar isn't necessary, i can do with a loader gif? Also, a lot of people have suggested using apc or the session variable available in php 5.4, are they the new standards instead of our old `$_FILES` array?

Please someone suggest how to achieve a file upload through ajax without a success message redirect on to the same page? A lot like what google plus and facebook uses while uploading files. Can anyone guide how they do it?

Comment: file upload is not possible in AJAX, these plugins are just showing they are uploading using ajax but they are using iframe to do so

Comment: @PankajKhairnar — Only true in old browsers. See XHR2 and File API.

Comment: It's easily possible using [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin. It will submit your form without refreshing the page. And can also give you success message. All without refreshing.

Comment: well, then what do you guys think google, facebook and the likes use to set up a cross-browser thing? especially for IE.

Comment: @Quentin : thank you for updating me, I guess he can not use it as not all browsers are supporting html5

Comment: @user1995997 is this jquery form plugin using iframe??

Comment: @NikhilVerma, No, it doesn't use iframe.

Comment: @user1995997 [link](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) on this, the examples of progress bar 1, 2 and 3 doesnt have source code download available, will i have to make that myself by reading about the whole plugin.

Comment: @NikhilVerma don't use plugin which is not using iframe, as it may run on your modern browser but will not work on browsers which doesn't support HTML5

Comment: @NikhilVerma, use [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm) tab instead. As I posted in answer.

Comment: @PankajKhairnar are you trying to say the jquery form plugin also won't work on browsers not supporting HTML5 as suggested in the answer below?

Comment: @NikhilVerma It will work on browsers not supporting HTML5, because It's there since html5 is not even out.

Comment: people this will be the first time i will be using jquery. i dont know how difficult is this ajaxForm tab to understand as on the link the example for file upload is given on another tab which doesnt explain much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with jquery, then best will be [jquery.form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm) plugin.

**HTML**

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' id='myForm' >
      <input type='file' name='img' />
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
<div id='output'></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var options = { 
          target:        '#output1',
          beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
          success:       showResponse
      }; 
      $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
})
```